# How to pass a certain LIST from one component to another component in REACT JS?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

**How to pass a certain LIST from one component to another component in REACT? This is the code, I could not pass the LIST to another components. I tried many ways but still couldn't pass the list.**

> Please me to solve the problem. So, I want to use the fetched LIST in another component.

**Child Component (in a same js of parent component)**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import FavoriteBorderIcon from '@material-ui/icons/FavoriteBorder';
import AddBoxIcon from '@material-ui/icons/AddBox';
import ExposureIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Exposure';
import HighlightsData from "./HighlightsData";


 export function HighlightsGrid(props){
 const [name, setTitle] = useState(props.title);
 const [image, setImage] = useState(props.imgsrc);
 const [amount, setAmount] = useState(props.price);

 const  LIST=[name, image, amount];
 
const onSubmit=()=>{
       const LIST={image, name, amount}
       console.log(datas)           
  }

 return(
    <div className="carddd">
        <li className="card-item double">
            <a href="#">
            <h1 className="heightLight">Highlight</h1>
            
            <div className="highlights">
                <figure className="card">
                <img src={props.imgsrc} alt="img." value={image} onChange={e=>setImage(e.target.value )}/>
                <button  onClick={onSubmit}  className="likeBtn">
                    <FavoriteBorderIcon />
                    400
                </button>
                <figcaption className="caption">
                    <h3 className="caption-title" value={name} onChange={e=>setTitle(e.target.value)}>{props.title}</h3>
                    <p>
                    {props.desc}
                    </p>
                </figcaption>
                </figure>
            </div>
            </a>
            <nav id="single-na" className="single-na menu" role="navigation">
            <ul>
                <li>
                <a value={amount} onChange={e=>setAmount(e.target.value )} className="default">
                    Nrs: <b>{props.price}</b>
                </a>
                </li>
                <li className="defs">
                <button>
                    <ExposureIcon />
                </button>
                add to shop
                </li>
                <li className="defs">
                <button >
                    <AddBoxIcon />
                </button>
                Add To Cart
                </li>
            </ul>
            </nav>
        </li>
        </div>
 )
}
```

**Parent component**

```
    function Highlights(){  
    return(    
    <>        
     {HighlightsData.map((val,index)=>
        {
            return(
            <HighlightsGrid
                key={val.id}
                imgsrc={val.imgsrc}
                title={val.title}
                desc={val.desc}
                price={val.price}
                />
                 );
        })}            
    </>
  );
}

 export {Highlights } ;
```

Comment: It is not clear in your question which component you are trying to pass the list to. I can see it is initialized in the child component and you seem to want to pass it somewhere onSubmit. Depending on that and the use case of that passed list, there are a couple options which I could suggest. Can you provide further details please?

Comment: I want to pass that List to another component not on parent (on other component suppose Favorite.jsx) 
const Favorite = [
      {"i wan to pass here"},
    {
      id:8,
      imgsrc:"Image 1.png",
      title:"shoes",
      price:"400000"
    },
    {
        id:9,
        imgsrc:"Image 1.png",
        title:"t shirt",
        price:"400000"
      },
     
  ];

Comment: I understand that, I'm trying to understand where your other component is located, is it a child of the one with the onSubmit function? If so, then you could simply pass it as prop via a state. If not, then perhaps the use of a context could help you out.

Comment: Other component is not child. I want to use that on other file  (i.e. favourite.jsx //this file contain just list)
 const Favorite= [ {"i wan to pass here"},]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The list can be passed from parent to child by simply passing list as props .

Parent.js

```
import React from "react";
import Child from "./Child";

import "./App.css";

function App() {
const List = [1, 3, 2, 4, 5];

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Child list={List} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

and Child.js as

```
import React from "react";
import { Card } from "@material-ui/core";

function Child({ list }) {
  return (
    <div>
      {list.map((value, index) => {
        return (
          <>
            <br />
            <Card
              style={{ marginTop: "3px", margin: "0px auto", width: "200px" }}
            >
              Double of {value} is {value * 2}
            </Card>
          </>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}

export default Child;
```

This will give the result

[image: Result]

Answer (score 0):

Considering you want to pass the list to another component that is neither child nor parent of the list's origin component, I would suggest the use of a [context](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext).

In short, you'll want to create a context provider at a higher level so that it is parent to both your list's origin (where you will update the context state) and the component where you need to use it (which will re-render when the context state changes).

I could provide a more practical answer if you provided us with more information as to where the component using the list is located and how it uses it.